# apache Tomcat installation directory in ubuntu / configure Tomcat in eclipse + ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

I installed java7 and ApacheTomcat7 in my Ubuntu12.04, and download eclipse EE. And now I have to configure my eclipse with tomcat. For I want to find the tomcat installation directory. How can I find it. I installed java and tomcat using Ubuntu software centre.

Comment: @ ShaggyInjun , I installed using ubuntu software centre

Comment: k, When you install tomcat using software center, it will install it according to Unix directory structure. I am not sure if eclipse  honours that structure. Download tar.gz file from apache and unzip it in your home directory. This way you'll be able to configure tomcat in eclipse.

Comment: this covers tomcat6 not 7 but same principle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356616/configuring-tomcat-6-with-eclipse-in-ubuntu
hope this is what you wanted

Comment: Answer you need (already linked to this question):

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1446684/273689

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**1.** Download the package "`apache-tomcat-7.0.6.tar.gz`" from the below link
http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi [tar.gz]

**2.** Now unpack it with the following command:

```
tar xvzf apache-tomcat-7.0.8.tar.gz
```

**3.** Then move to more appropriate directory, in our case in `/usr/share/tomcat7`, but can be in any directory. We do this with the command:

```
sudo mv apache-tomcat-7.0.8/ /usr/share/tomcat7
```

**4.** Now define the environment variables `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME`. This file is in the "environment" in / etc. Command to edit the file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

**5.** Here we record the routes where we have installed Java in my case this is as follows:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_23"
JRE_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_23/jre"
PATH="...(other path):$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME"
```

**6. IMPORTANT:** Verify the routes where they have installed Java.

sometimes tomcat does not recognize, but a surefire way of recognizing that tomcat is to define the file paths inside "`catalina.sh`" located in `tomcat7/bin`. To modify this file use the command:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh
```

Now insert the `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` after the first line, so the file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_23"
JRE_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_23/jre"
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF)...
#...
#...
....
```

Now configure Tomcat users, this is done in the file "`tomcat-users.xml`" directory `tomcat7/conf`. Command to edit the file:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

**7.** Unlike previous versions, the administrator should own role "manager" now it should be "`manager-gui`"to operate on the web administration tomcat7. The file would be as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>

<user username="usuario" password="contrasena" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui,manager,admin,manager-script,admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**8.** For further info look [here](http://diegobenna.blogspot.in/2011/01/install-tomcat-7-in-ubuntu-1010.html)
[set-up-eclipse-and-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-12-04](http://lackovic.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/set-up-eclipse-and-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-12-04-to-create-java-restful-web-services-with-jersey/)
[cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-eclipse-tomcat](http://hariprasad.info/cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-eclipse-tomcat/)

Comment: "Reinstall tomcat to the one folder" is not an answer to the main question. It's just a oblivious workaround "how to make your own tomcat install directory".

Comment: @FrankovskyiBogdan, If you really know anything about installation/ installation Issue for the above question, you could answer in better way, else you can improve the answer (given by me) to a generic way. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: please, see my comment above.

Comment: -1: While the procedures may work, almost every step violates good housekeeping guidelines: It mixes an install from repository with a downloaded one (`/usr/share/tomcat7`), hardcode java paths in `/etc/environment` and gives way too much roles in `tomcat_users.xml` (some of them outdated)

Comment: We have better solution for giving paths 1. In **.bashrc** file (User level access). 2. In **setenv.sh** file which must be created inside **tomcat/bin/** directory (tomcat level access).

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can use Tomcat from Ubuntu repository with Eclipse (at least with Kepler version). It just requires couple of additional steps.

1. Open Eclipse. Press File ⇒ New ⇒ Other... ⇒ Servers ⇒ Server ⇒ Next > ⇒ Apache ⇒ Tomcat v7.0 Server
2. Select Tomcat Installation Directory: /usr/share/tomcat7
3. Click Finish, ignore error message, click Finish again
4. Copy Tomcat configuration to workspace executing from terminal:

   ```
   sudo cp -r /etc/tomcat7/* ~/workspace/Servers/Tomcat\ v7.0\ Server\ at\ localhost-config/
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/workspace/Servers/Tomcat\ v7.0\ Server\ at\ localhost-config/
   ```
5. Concat policy files into one file:

   ```
   cd ~/workspace/Servers/Tomcat\ v7.0\ Server\ at\ localhost-config/
   cat policy.d/* > catalina.policy
   ```
6. Either shutdown tomcat7 service every time before running it from Eclipse, or edit tomcat's ports in config files of your workspace (I suggest editing configs):

   ```
   gedit ~/workspace/Servers/Tomcat\ v7.0\ Server\ at\ localhost-config/server.xml
   ```

   You are interested in changing ports 8080, 8009 and 8005 (to, say, 9090, 9009 and 9005).
7. Return to Eclipse, select 'Servers' in Project Explorer (left panel), press F5, to refresh it.
8. Start Tomcat from Eclipse (see Servers tab in the bottom panel of Eclipse).

I wrote this answer based on [my article](http://sukharevd.net/environment-for-j2ee-development-under-ubuntu.html#eclipsetomcat). It's a bit more detailed, so refer to it if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can install tomcat from repository.

1. search for tomcat.

   ```
   sudo apt-cache search tomcat
   ```
2. Install tomcat admin and tomcat

   ```
   sudo apt-get install tomcat7-admin
   sudo apt-get install tomcat7
   ```
3. Check for tomcat status

   ```
   sudo service tomcat7 status
   ```
4. Start and stop tomcat

   ```
   sudo service tomcat7 start
   sudo service tomcat7 stop
   ```

Bin folder for tomcat7 is at /usr/share/tomcat7 and logs and config are are at /usr/lib/tomcat7

Source: http://www.allaboutjava.club/linux/linux-install-tomcat7-on-ubuntu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11216989)

Comment: Point noted. Edited the answer. @FabioLamanna : thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

I like to use packages from the repository every time possible.

In this case:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-user
sudo tomcat7-instance-create /srv/tomcats/ubuntu
sudo ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/lib /srv/tomcats/ubuntu/
```

For tomcat6 the ln step can be skipped.

Then just use this path to add a tomcat7 server on eclipse.
Tested on 14.04 and eclipse kepler sr2. Should work on 12.04.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use by default command, like `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`.

If you follow the above command then you will face lots of problem because `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` will be in different locations. In that case you have to declare environment variable separately.

Comment: Note that such problems are Eclipse's fault, not Tomcat's (or Ubuntu repository): Eclipse is unable to handle `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` being distinct paths. It expects both to be the same, while it should not assume so.

Comment: And the solution to this problem is to create a "/usr/share/tomcat" directory with symbolic links to the "different places".  Many distros do this for you automatically; it's easy to do manually or with a shell script: [Configuring Tomcat in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356616/configuring-tomcat-6-with-eclipse-in-ubuntu)