# The Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder lib/jasper-el.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, liferay, liferay-ide

I have downloaded the Liferay Portal 6.1
Community Edition bundled with tomcat. Then i have downloaded the SDK for liferay. Following the steps given in this [site](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial) to configure eclipse with liferay when i reach at the step 4 i got the following error.
[image]

All the related [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356616/configuring-tomcat-6-with-eclipse-in-ubuntu) are specific to ubuntu. But i am using windows 7 64 bit. I am not getting how to solve this problem. All the files are present then why its showing me this error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is more appropriate for forums relating to that software. This is a highly specific question.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Thanks for suggestion. But i think SO is a Father of all forums and also i have never used any other forum before could you please recommend any where community is as much active as in SO?

Comment: Eclipse forums, or Liferay forums, or Tomcat forums. All the people on those forums are looking to help people with said software, this site is designed to help people with general coding issues.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Well SO never disappointed me before. I hope someone here will solve my problem soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be trying to create a `Liferay v6.0 Tomcat Runtime` and then pointing the directory to a Liferay v6.1 Tomcat runtime (notice the 6.1.1 in the install path).  So go back to the previous screen and choose `Liferay v6.1 Tomcat Runtime` instead.  If you don't have v6.1 then you need to make sure you have the latest version of [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE) installed (lastest version is 1.6.1).

Comment: +1 I have resolved my problem.. i am accepting your answer because you were very close to the actual solution. Actually i was choosing tomcat 6 but the bundle contains tomcat 7.

Comment: Correct, the 6.0 Liferay bundle includes Tomcat 6 and the 6.1 Liferay bundle has Tomcat 7 included.  So that is the underlying reason for the error.