# Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder lib/jasper-el.jar

Tags: apache

When i try to add new server in eclipse kepler it shows this error.I refered this previous question but not work here

[image]

Refered question:[The Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder lib/jasper-el.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568623/the-tomcat-installation-directory-is-not-valid-it-is-missing-expected-file-or-f)